# python writing into json files witout overwriting

Tags: json, python-3.x

How can I write into a JSON file without overwriting things?
like
file.json contains

```
{
    "today date" : {
        "sec": 04
        "min": 10
    }
}
```

I want to add info the next time I open this like

```
{
    "today date" : {
        "sec": 04
        "min": 10
    }
    "other day": {
        "sec": "other"
        "min": "other min"
    }


}
```

so add data without overwriting the data that was before.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are you storing the json data in your code? Is it a json object or just a string?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, I did nothing.

Comment: you can read the whole JSON file and then add required details to generated python object then dump it into the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're treating the json as text, it's easy to insert the new data into the existing file.

```
newdata = """"other day": {
        "sec": "other"
        "min": "other min"
    }"""

jsonfile = 'data.json'

# read current json file
with open(jsonfile,'r') as f:
     curdata = f.read().strip()

# merge new data
fulldata = curdata[0:-1].strip() + ",\n" + newdata + "\n}"

# write full data
with open(jsonfile,'w') as f:
     f.write(fulldata)
```